# Is there a way to run a command after a specified command

Tags: shell, unix, zsh

Im trying to find a way to run a simple echo command after i run a separate command.

In this specific case I am trying to run a command like 
`echo 'dont forget to add the newly created app to settings'`
after i run 
`python manage.py createapp newAppName`

Comment: If the answer by John Kugelman does not fulfil your needs, you will have to be more precise in explaining, what you want to achieve. You also should in this case make up your mind, whether you want a _zsh_ solutions or a _shell_ solution (you provided both tags).

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens naturally if you write one statement after the other. In a script, write:

```
python manage.py createapp newAppName
echo 'dont forget to add the newly created app to settings'
```

If you're typing the commands interactively you might want them on one line. Use `;`:

```
python manage.py createapp newAppName; echo 'dont forget to add the newly created app to settings'
```

Or use `&&` to only run `echo` if `manage.py` succeeds:

```
python manage.py createapp newAppName && echo 'dont forget to add the newly created app to settings'
```

Comment: I think the intent is to configure the shell so that the given Python command "triggers" the `echo` command, rather than executing the `echo` explicitly.